# There are/it is two steps

Tags: meaning

**I think all three are correct. Am I right?**

> 1 There are two steps in a meter.
>
> 2 It is two steps in a meter.
>
> 3 Two steps amount to a meter.

Comment: If your meaning is that the length of someone’s pace is 500 mm, then your first sentence is idiomatic and your third is ok, depending on context, but your second simply doesn’t fly (i.e., it’s not at all idiomatic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"There are ..." and "Two steps amount to..."  both are idiomatic, but the only context I can think of, where "It is two steps in a meter" would be idiomatic, is when correcting someone:

> This metric system really has me all confused. There are ten steps to a meter, right?
>
> -- No, it's two steps to a meter.

There, you are converting meters to steps, and "There are" is the usual form for that kind of statement:

> There are x [units] in|to a [y].

Of course, there are many other contexts where "It is two" can be used.

> It's two days until school's out for the summer!
>
> It's two minutes under the broiler and then quickly out when browning the custard.

Comment: Where I live, a metre is a unit of length, and a 'meter' is something that measures electricity or gas.

Comment: British shenanigans

Comment: The British have always had a reputation for nuance.

Comment: It's two days until school's out for the summer! - There are two days until school's out for the summer! - Any difference?

Comment: No difference in the number of days. There's a difference in register. "It's two days" is conversational and informal whereas "There are" is neutral and could be used in informal and formal contexts.

Comment: @user1425 not only the British.  Australia, New Zealand, and Canada all use "metre" as the spelling for the unit of measurement.